# SQL Pivot on Foreign Key but display different column header

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had written a stored procedure that would first get a list of columns which were distinct account descriptions and use those to pivot on for getting daily monetary values per account.  The problem I encountered is the end user has instances where they have the same Account description for multiple accounts so I am now using AccountID's to pivot on.

Below you will find my query to get Distinct Account ID's and then to create the pivot table.  My end goal is that the current column headers for the user are useless i.e. "1504" "1505" "1683" etc. These have no meaning to them.  How can I either rename column headers of a result set or somehow use a pivot based on distinct account ID's while displaying a description instead.  GLAccounts.Description is the column with the description I would like to display instead of the GLAccounts.AccountID.

```
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(AccountID)
                FROM (
                    SELECT DISTINCT GLAccounts.AccountID AS AccountID
                    FROM GeneralLedger
                    INNER JOIN DailyFiles ON GeneralLedger.DailyFileID = DailyFiles.DailyFileID
                    Inner Join GLAccounts ON GeneralLedger.AccountID = GLAccounts.AccountID
                    -- Get All Daily Files for company and date range
                    INNER JOIN
                    (SELECT DailyFileID
                    FROM DailyFiles
                    WHERE (DailyFiles.DailyFileDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, @MTDStart, 102)) AND (DailyFiles.DailyFileDate <= CONVERT(DATETIME, @MTDEnd, 102))
                    AND CompanyID = @CompanyID) AS DAILYFILEIDS ON GeneralLedger.DailyFileID = DAILYFILEIDS.DailyFileID
                ) x
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

SET @query = N'SELECT A.*
        from(
            SELECT SummedAccounts.Date, SUM(SummedAccounts.DayTotal) AS DayTotal, SummedAccounts.AccountID AS AccountID
            FROM(SELECT DailyFiles.DailyFileDate AS Date, IIF(GLAccounts.FriendlyName IS NOT NULL AND GLAccounts.FriendlyName <> '''', GLAccounts.FriendlyName, GLAccounts.Description) as AccountDescription, IIF(GeneralLedger.SavedToCredit = 1,
            --Saved To Credit Is True
            IIF(AccountTYpes.PositiveToCredit = 1, (SUM(GeneralLedger.Credit + GeneralLedger.Debit)), (SUM(GeneralLedger.Credit + GeneralLedger.Debit) * -1)),
            --Saved To Credit Is False
            IIF(AccountTYpes.PositiveToCredit = 1, ( SUM(GeneralLedger.Credit + GeneralLedger.Debit) * -1), (SUM(GeneralLedger.Credit + GeneralLedger.Debit)))) AS DayTotal, GeneralLedger.SavedToCredit, AccountTypes.PositiveToCredit, GeneralLedger.AccountID AS AccountID
            FROM GeneralLedger
            INNER JOIN DailyFiles ON GeneralLedger.DailyFileID = DailyFiles.DailyFileID
            Inner Join GLAccounts ON GeneralLedger.AccountID = GLAccounts.AccountID
            INNER JOIN AccountTypes ON AccountTypes.AccountTypeID = GLAccounts.AccountTypeID
            -- Get All Daily Files for company and date range
            INNER JOIN
            (SELECT DailyFileID
            FROM DailyFiles
            WHERE (DailyFiles.DailyFileDate >= @MTDStart) AND (DailyFiles.DailyFileDate <= @MTDEnd)
            AND CompanyID = @CompanyID) AS DAILYFILEIDS ON GeneralLedger.DailyFileID = DAILYFILEIDS.DailyFileID 
            GROUP BY GeneralLedger.AccountID, DailyFiles.DailyFileDate, GLAccounts.FriendlyName, GLAccounts.Description, GeneralLedger.SavedToCredit, AccountTypes.PositiveToCredit) SummedAccounts             
            GROUP BY SummedAccounts.Date, SummedAccounts.AccountID
        ) y
        pivot
        (
            min(DayTotal)
            for AccountID in (' + @cols + ')
        ) A'
```

**Result Sets Look Like:**

[image: Stack Overflow Pivot Question 1]

[image: Stack Overflow Pivot Question 2]

Comment: You've not said what column header *should* be displayed for these columns. What's the rule/logic for coming up with something other than `1504`, etc?

Comment: I am pulling the AccountID and Description from my GLAccounts Table.  I want the Description field to display instead of the AccountID however I need the uniqueness of AccountID.  I initially had selected Description instead of AccountID in my query to get @cols and then I had pivoted on Description however because the user has multiple descriptions that may not be unique I end up missing accounts in my summary.  Example of Descriptions: "Food Sales", "Beverage Sales", "Postage", "Postage".